# project has stopped android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android

I know that this question is have asked many times and respective solution is on that portal, but none of them solve my problem.

I created an android project on android studio 3.0.1 and when I click on green symbol to run emulator, on AVD it shows me project has stopped--Open app again.

[image]

I saw the suggestion for this problem as Logcat and breakpoint and so on. But I don't know how actually use it.

I am new on android development so please help me how to use logcat or suggest me any other way to fix this problem my logcat  is as follow:-

```
06-03 13:18:39.644 6812-6812/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.ram.projects6b, PID: 6812
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ram.projects6b/com.example.ram.projects6b.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Fab
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Fab
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Fab
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Fab" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ram.projects6b-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ram.projects6b-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:286)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                     at com.example.ram.projects6b.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: The problem may because of Float Action Button control. It is difficult because you don't provide any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem describe with this error log:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Fab
                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Fab
                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Fab" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
```

You're using incorrect View tag in your layout. You're using:

```
android.support.v7.widget.Fab
```

where there is no `Fab` View in Support library.

Probably what you wanted is [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton):

```
android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Comment: Glad it help you!